# Не удаётся скомпилировать код с файлом в качестве аргумента main (file.open(argv[1]))

Tags: c++, visual-studio

В среде MVS2015 следующий код и вообще любой подобный:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream input(argv[1]);  *//строка с исключением*
    cout << "File:" << argv[1];
    system("pause");
}
```

Выдаёт следующее исключение на этапе компиляции (Release):

```
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x742C1912 (ucrtbase.dll) в Test.exe: Недопустимый параметр был передан функции, для которой недопустимые параметры вызывают неустранимую ошибку.
```

Как побороть напасть и с чем она связана? Тоже самое встречалось и на других компьютерах, а вот по словам других людей в других средах код работает корректно.
Совет переходить на другую среду разработки мало похож на полезный :)

Спасибо!

Comment: А вы не забыли передать что-то (имя файла) в командной строке?...

Comment: Это непохоже на сообщение этапа компиляции, скорее всего это ошибка во время исполнения. Прежде чем обращаться к `argv[1]` следует проверить, что `1 < argc`.

Comment: @VTT Вы оказались правы, проверка вида: `if (argc<2) return;` решила проблему. Почему-то до этого проверка не помогала, либо я просто её неправильно реализовывал... Спасибо!